# Google App Engine : Fatal error: require on requiring CloudStorageClient

Tags: php, google-app-engine, zend-framework, socialengine

I'm trying to install an old kind of framework (Social Engine 4) which is using Zend Framework 1 on its core.

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   'google/appengine/ext/cloud_storage_streams/CloudStorageClient.php'
>
> (include_path=':PEAR:.')
>   in
>
> /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/autoloader.php
>   on line 549

I'm using the Google App Launcher in mac and also I'm assuming the all google app engine related sdk's are automatically loaded by the autoloader.php

Has anyone encountered this kind of error in Google App Engine?

app.yml config:

```
application: application-id
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /install/(.*\.(htm|html|css|js))$
  static_files: install/\1
  upload: install/.*\.(htm|html|css|js)$
  application_readable: true

- url: /install/(.*\.(jpg|png))$
  static_files: install/\1
  upload: install/.*\.(jpg|png)$
  application_readable: true

- url: /install/index.php
  script: install/index.php

- url: /(.+)?/?
  script: index.php
```

Comment: what version of the SDK do you have?

Comment: I'm using the latest version they have on their site **1.9.27 - 2015-09-16** .

Comment: do you set the include path yourself manually in the code somewhere? from the error message above it looks like it.